# Understanding why `DegradedArray` emails are sent in this case

Tags: raid, mdadm

On Sunday at 13:15, I removed a drive from my RAID1 which previously consisted of 2 drives by physically disconnecting the drive. `mdadm` immediately sent me an email titled `Fail event on /dev/md0:christoph-pi`. I'm changing my RAID, the old one currently is only read from, and I still have all the data stored on the other disk, so degrading it isn't a problem but gives me an extra slot.

However, on Monday at 07:36, I received an email titled `DegradedArray event on /dev/md0:christoph-pi`, and on Tuesday (today) another one with the same title at the same time of the day (07:36).

I first thought that it's a periodic scan each day at 07:36 and it's just a bit weird that it's called a "DegradedArray **event**", but I since have read what the man page of `mdadm` says about `DegradedArray` messages:

> A newly noticed array appears to be degraded. This message is not generated when mdadm notices a drive failure which causes degradation, but only when mdadm notices that an array is degraded when it first sees the array. (syslog priority: Critical)

Clearly, `mdadm` knows about the array for months, and it knows about the missing disk since Sunday, 13:15. Why do I receive these massages?

The contents of the emails can be found here: http://pastebin.com/cGU3CvhP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably those emails are sent as a result of

```
mdadm --monitor --scan --oneshot
```

in `/etc/cron.daily/mdadm`, which causes `mdadm` to “notice” the degraded array every day. This involves a new `mdadm` process running a new scan every day, so it’s noticing the degraded array for the first time every time.